# html / php redirect to other file

Tags: php, html

We have file A.html file B.php and File C.php
I made a button that redirects from A to B and takes values provided by user in A:

```
<form action="B" method=post>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Zrob" /></td></tr>
```

Now i wanted to create another, similar button in A that takes us to C in which you can have a look at some list and button in C that takes us back to A so i did this in file A:

```
<form action="C" method=post>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Cena" /></td>
</tr>
```

and this in C:

```
<form action="A" method=post>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Powrot" /></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that when you leave A and go back you loose all provided values
how to prevent it ?
I saw some solutions in JS but I wonder if it's possible to be done using html and php only?

Comment: Use `header('Location:file.php');` to go forward but going back will ALWAYS lose form fields, unless you do a check on the value of the input and if it is filled out, re-assign the value to that input and assign the value the submitted

Comment: @clearshot66 Or better still `header('Location: file.php');`

Comment: so i need to make a "function inside a button" that saves all provided values to POST variables and than in another button a function that fills empty spaces with values provided before we left the page ?

Comment: There's a few options if you want to keep historic variable data when navigating pages. 1. Sessions (session array would be best); 2. iterate your `$_POST` and construct a "back" button containing `$_GET` variables that you can check on your other page; 3. Iterate `$_POST` and use hidden fields with a "back" button sending the form. There's possibly much more ways to handle this but those are the 3 I use depending on the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few options if you want to keep historic variable data when navigating pages.

1. Sessions (session array would be best);
2. iterate your $_POST and construct a "back" button containing $_GET variables that you can check on your other page;
3. Iterate $_POST and use hidden fields with a "back" button sending the form.

There's possibly much more ways to handle this but those are the 3 I use depending on the situation